# Encryption in both browser client and server side code

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption

i want to encrypt data in javascript and posted data want to decrypt in c# code.
Is there any idea or any code that can do this think with same algorithm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.net C# Encryption/Decryption on Client and server Side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775909/asp-net-c-sharp-encryption-decryption-on-client-and-server-side) (not quite the same but there's a few pointers in that answer too). Client side encryption isn't going to give you anything over SSL for example, and might actually expose you to different attacks if you trust the data more.

Comment: I'd just use SSL.

Comment: Near duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774627/compatible-encryption-libraries-between-client-a-server-side-javascript-c-sh?rq=1  See John Skeet's comment there for why SSL is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Since `JavaScript` is executed in the end-user's webbrowser, your encryption code and algorithm is exposed. That means that the code is likely to be very easy to reverse and used against you.

A much better alternative to what you're asking for is using SSL to send the data securely over Internet. If you'd need, you could then encrypt the data once it reaches your server and before it is stored in your database or is passed on to another system.

See [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/#IISManager) for information about activating `SSL` on your website (if you're running `IIS 7`).